# Use PHP for splitting on spaces and brackets

Tags: php, regex

I have this string in `$s`:

> ben say (#yellow) hey

At the moment I'm using:

```
$parts = array_filter(preg_split('/\s+/', $s));
```

So i have an output of array elements:

```
[0] ben
[1] say
[2] (#yellow)
[3] hey
```

Would it be possible to create an array structure like this:

```
[0] ben
[1] say
[2] (
[3] #yellow
[4] )
[5] hey
```

Comment: It would, but to write a correct program you need to know its description. An example is not a description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could split it by `Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Width Assertions`:

```
$parts = array_filter(preg_split('/\s+|(?=[()])|(?<=[()])/', $s));
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can try this replacement:

```
$s = str_replace(array('(', ')'), array('( ', ' )'), $s);
$parts = array_filter(preg_split('/\s+/', $s));
```

The trick here is to add a space between your `(` and the word so that it gets splitted. However, it will only work specific to your example. Things like `((` might cause some unwanted results. If so you can try using preg_replace instead.

Comment: thanks @Björn - was testing on a web tester and it required the additional slash.

Comment: Yeah, my guess was that you did. NP. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// function to explode on multiple delimiters
function multi_explode($pattern, $string, $standardDelimiter = ':')
{
    // replace delimiters with standard delimiter, also removing redundant delimiters
    $string = preg_replace(array($pattern, "/{$standardDelimiter}+/s"), $standardDelimiter, $string);

    // return the results of explode
    return explode($standardDelimiter, $string);
}

// test

    // set up variables
    $string = "zero  one | two :three/ four\ five:: six|| seven eight nine\n ten \televen twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen";
    $pattern = '/[:\|\\\\\/\s]/';  // colon (:), pipe (escaped '\|'), slashes (escaped '\\\\' and '\/'), white space (\s)

    // call function
    $result = multi_explode($pattern, $string);

    // display results
    var_dump($result);

?>
```

Source : http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php Examples

Answer (score 0):

A one liner which will work exactly as wanted (you don't even need `array_filter`):

```
$s = "ben say (ewfs) as";
$parts = preg_split('/\s+|(\()|(\))/', $s, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)

/*
Array(
  0 => "ben",
  1 => "say",
  2 => "(",
  3 => "ewfs",
  4 => ")",
  5 => "as",
)
*/
```

Answer (score -2):

this will work:

```
$parts = array_filter(preg_split('/[\s\(\)]+/', $s));
```

Comment: like the answer by @Zagorax, your brackets will be split.

Comment: oops sorry, didn't noticed that the brackets should be maintained